# Add new attribute calculated based on other attributes

Tags: weka

I'm starting with WEKA and want to achieve the following.

I have file with 2 attributes: user_id, user_age.
I can successfully load data using WEKA API and get `Instances` object.

Now I want to calculate new attribute user_age_range - like (0-18) - 0, (19-25) - 1, etc.

Is there a way to calculate this attribute using WEKA Filters?
Also I would like not to iterate manually through all instances, but to define method that operates on single `Instance` and use some filter (or other abstraction) that'll apply corresponding "transformation" to all instances.

Please advice - how I could achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is `MathExpression` is the best solution for this task?

Answer (score 0):

After looking through the docs I found one or two filters that you could use in conjunction to achieve what you want.

http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/filters/unsupervised/attribute/Copy.html

Use copy to create a copy that you will transform.

http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/filters/unsupervised/attribute/NumericTransform.html

The numeric transform takes a class and a method option, you could write your own class that boxes the ages into the ranges you want and supply this class and method as your options.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Using a csv file you can do that on Excel. 
If you are using arff files, convert it to csv and then you can add the columns that you want depending on the number of new attributes and then just do whatever you want to do with one or more atributes on the first row. Extend that to all rows and it's done.